# Empty String in Solr

Tags: solr

I have a custom field to be Indexed for each Item. If it does not get the value it returns `string.Empty`.
Before when Item's searched in Solr, whose custom fields are string.empty the field was not present in the item. But recently after Indexing for an item, the custom field with empty string is coming in the Solr.
So suppose my custom field name is `custom_fac_s`. earlier when Solr is queried like: `custom_fac_s: ""`, it did not return any item, but recently it does.
**Is there a change in Solr Behaviour?**
I am using Sitecore 9.
 The field is mapped in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration.config` as below:

```
<field fieldName="Custom_Fac" storageType="yes" returntype="string" indexType="untokenized">extensions.Search.AddCustomFacetIndexField,extensions</field>
```

Comment: Sitecore does not store empty strings and nulls in your index because they waste space. make sure you don't have `nullValue="NULLVALUE" emptyString="EMPTYVALUE"` parameters in config. Also try to run your query against the Solr directly.

Comment: If the code in your computed field returns null for some items, `custom_fac_s` will not be present for the items in Solr. However, returning `string.Empty` will have make the field present in the documents.